# How to remove hieroglyphs from message, recieved on Windows 10 machine?

Tags: c#, smtp, windows-10, email-attachments

I have an app, which sends e-mail messages with some pictures attached, using SmtpClient class. I've noticed strange thing. After recieving the message on some e-mail client(not in browser) on Windows 10 computer - there are a lot of hieroglyph symbols at the end of the message body. Imagine situation: you are trying to send message using hands(not from code). You can simply attach some picture to the message by their paths so, that they are really simple attachments. But you can also crop some image from the Paint and insert it into the body - in that case the cropped image will be seen in the body and it will be attached to the message, too. So I think, that SmtpClient class works like the second variant. And the hieroglyphs are the encoded image, which was cropped and inserted into the body. The question is, why does that happen only on Windows 10 and only using e-mail client programs?

I've tried to attach pictures at first, and only after that the body has been filled. The second idea was to fill the body and remember it, assigning it to temporary variable, then attaching files, and after that clearing current body value and assigning temporary variable to it. Such ways didn't help.

Making message:

```
    public MailMessage MakeMessage()
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@address.com", Name);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to@address.com");


        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

        message.Body = MessageText; // typed text           
        string temp = message.Body;

        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        message.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(Mail);            

        CreateAttachments(message);

        message.Body = null;
        message.Body = temp;

        return message;
    }
```

During using the app - some screenshots can be created, storing dynamicly. 
So this method creates physical files for that screenshots and then attaches them to the message:

```
    public void CreateAttachments(MailMessage message)
    {
        foreach (var pict in FeedBackHelper.ScreenshotsCollection)
        {
            if (pict.IsChecked)
            {
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(pict.Image));

                var pathToPicture = Path.Combine(FeedBackHelper.feedBackTempPath, $"{pict.Name}.jpg");

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToPicture, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fileStream);
                }
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(pathToPicture));
            }
        }

    }
```

I've checked this, sending messages on 3 Windows 7 and 3 windows 10 computers. As result messages with image attachments look like they must on Windows 7 in each e-mail client or browser, but on Windows 10 messages consist of simple attachment and body with a lot of hieroglyphs at the end. Any ideas?

Comment: "Lots of hieroglyphs" Sounds like an encoding issue

Comment: Yes, but they appear only, when I try to attach pictures to the message @MindSwipe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was in encoding. Changed Unicode on UTF-8, although UTF-7 works, too.
But that behavior has really confused me.